# Teamcity build leaves all code behind in the folder

Tags: c#, build, msbuild, teamcity

I've a problem with teamcity. The build works fine after svn checkout and it moves all files in the right folder, but i still get the aspx.cs files of the project.
What's the best way to delete them?

Answer (score 0):

Is your intent to delete everything?  If so, setting the build parameter `system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir.expireHours` to `0` will cause TeamCity to delete the checkout directory immediately after the build completes.  [Additional options](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Checkout+Directory) are available.

Comment: Nope, the build generates the bin folder with all dll, but leaves all the code behind of the pages. Ex. index.aspx and index.aspx.cs. The file index.asp.cs must be deleted.

Comment: If you want just the source to be immediately deleted, I'd copy off the folder(s) that you want to preserve (either as artifacts or via a build step) and then clear the checkout directory as above.  That said, would you mind saying more about what you're trying to achieve? I'm curious as to why you want to immediately delete the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it leaves sources there, deleting sources is not part of build. You should publish your site first. It can be published into folder you set up or into deployment package. This package can be published as build artifact.